# Groovy: How can I include backslashes inside a string without escaping?

Tags: string, groovy, scripting

I want to use the following string literal inside my groovy program without having to escape the backslashes:

```
C:\dev\username
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

## String (Single Quotes) & GStrings (Double Quotes)

```
def aString = 'C:\dev\username'
def aGString = "C:\dev\username"
```

- Doesn't work because \ has special meaning and is used to escape other characters
- I end up having to escape \ with another \

```
def s = 'C:\\dev\\username'
```

## Slashy String & Dollar Slashy String

Works for some strings, like the following

```
def slashy = /C:\windows\system32/
def dollarSlashy = $/C:\windows\system32/$
```

But it interprets \u as having special meaning (the following don't work):

```
def s1 = /C:\dev\username/
def s2 = $/C:\dev\username/$
```

- Groovy:Did not find four digit hex character code

Comment: You can't. `\` had a special meaning in Java and groovy, so you would need to escape them. If it's a path for a for, you should be able to use forward slashes though

Comment: @tim_yates Why does def slashy = /C:\windows\system32/ seems to work then?

Comment: It works to it thinks you're defining a Unicode char, as you have found

Comment: @MikeR '/.../' is short for "create me a pattern" so you might at the end of the day run in further/other problems.

Comment: Alternate solution: Because in Windows `/` can be used instead of `\ ` as a path separator, you can simply use `def path = "C:/windows/system32/"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow, another gotcha with putting Windows files paths in slashy strings. Nice catch. The gotcha I've encountered before was including a trailing backslash on the path, e.g. `/C:\path\/`, which results in an `unexpected char: 0xFFFF` error.

Anyways, for the sake of an answer, given that Windows paths are case insensitive, why not exploit it for once?

```
def s = /C:\DEV\USERNAME/
```

The `\u` unicode character escape sequence *is* case sensitive.

Comment: Windows paths are by default configured to be case-insensitive, but they are not (i.e. never) case-unaware. So if what want to *create* a directory called "username" then you *must* use the lowercase "...\username".

Comment: The `unexpected char: 0xFFFF` error is still an issue as of Groovy `2.4.10`. Using the dollar slashy String fixes the issue ala `$/C:\Path\To\Some\Place\/$`

Comment: Windows paths are *by default* case insensitive. But a user can turn on case sensitivity with `ObCaseInsensitive` registry key (globally) or `fsutil setCaseSensitiveInfo` (per folder). So, code based on this answer will work incorrectly. This answer should not be accepted!