# Jmeter JSR223 PostProcessor unexpected char: '\'

Tags: jmeter

I am using groovy JSR223 Post processor to process response and save to file.

Here is my configuration

in test plan adding UDV:

```
USER_PATH : ${__groovy(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__groovy(File.separator)}
```

JSR223 PostProcessor Script

```
def x = var.get ("${USER_PATH}");

out.print(x);
```

and i got following error in jmeter log viewer

```
ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script18.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 21.
   def x = var.get ("C:\Users\wins\learn\test\");
```

Seems groovy expected double slash from USER_PATH variable?
what should i do to avoid unexpected char error from groovy?

thanks

Comment: Following this answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790056/groovy-how-can-i-include-backslashes-inside-a-string-without-escaping)

Comment: path is from jmeter USER_PATH : ${__groovy(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__groovy(File.separator)} I can not modify the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the JSR223 PostProcessor Script is wrong:

1. The keyword for accessing JMeter Variables is [`vars`](https://www.google.gr/search?q=jmetervariables&oq=jmetervariables&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.1794j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
2. You should remove dollar sign and curly braces from your `USER_PATH` expression
3. [`OUT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) shorthand is case sensitive

Fixed code will be

```
def x = vars.get ("USER_PATH");
OUT.print(x);
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, it works. When i should use ${} to access prop or variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get by variable key and not value, change code to:

```
  def x = vars.get("USER_PATH");
```